# Node node-cmd + readline bugging on space

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to experiment node-cmd + readline to make some folders from a list on txt

```
my **list.txt**
Steve Walker
Emily Campbell
Jessica Jones
Chloe Winter
```

The code should get this names and make some folders with their names

**Code:**

```
var cmd = require('node-cmd');

function processFile(inputFile) {
    var fs = require('fs'),
        readline = require('readline'),
        instream = fs.createReadStream(inputFile),
        outstream = new (require('stream'))(),
        rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);

    let linenumber = 1;

    rl.on('line', function (line) {
        console.log("("+ linenumber + ")" + line);
        linenumber += 1;

        cmd.run('mkdir ' + line);
    });

    rl.on('close', function (line) {
        cmd.get(
            'ls',
            function(err, data, stderr){
                console.log('the current dir contains these files :\n\n',data)
            }
        );
        console.log('done reading file.');
    });
}
processFile('list.txt');
```

But it's not, it's getting the name, but it's bugging when mkdir run, it's running without the spaces, like you can see on console log print:

**Console:**

```
~/node/mai$ node index
(1)Steve Walker
(2)Emily Campbell
(3)Jessica Jones
(4)Chloe Winter
done reading file.
the current dir contains these files :

 Campbell
Chloe
Emily
index.js
Jessica
Jones
list.txt
node_modules
package.json
package-lock.json
Steve
Walker
Winter
```

Is anybody can help me???
What should i do to it work?